# Generate JSF2 CRUD's - Can I create the bean and xhtml automatically for any entity?

Tags: java, jsf-2, xhtml, code-generation, hibernate-tools

I'm looking for any kind of software which allows me to generate, in an automatically way, the MVC files (a bean and a xhtml view) of any CRUD of any entity using Java Server Faces 2 and Richfaces 4 technologies.

I think one solution would be to use the Hibernate Tools plugin for Eclipse, creating an exporter like the Dao code generator but I don't know if it is possible or how can i do that. I search but I didn't find any documentation about it.

Do you know which is the best solution for this issue? Any other interesting software?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans has that feature, based on an entity class it can generate CRUD. This is what it generates for each entity you choose:

- a stateless session bean that extends AbstractFacade.java
- a JSF session-scoped, managed bean
- a directory containing four Facelets files for CRUD capabilities (Create.xhtml, Edit.xhtml, List.xhtml, and View.xhtml)

also it will generate:

- the AbstractFacade.java class that contains the business logic for
  creation, retrieval, modification and removal of entity instances
- utility classes used by the JSF managed beans (JsfUtil, PaginationHelper)
- a properties bundle for localized messages, and a corresponding entry in the project's Faces configuration file (A faces-config.xml
  file is created if one does not already exist.)
- auxiliary web files, including a default stylesheet for rendered components, and a Facelets template file

you'll have to update the generate code to use richfaces.

Here's a tutorial on how to do it:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html