# Java CRUD class generator for Intellij Idea

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

Is there a way to automaticaly generate CRUD class for Hibernate Entity in Spring MVC using the IntelliJ Idea IDE? I found some possibility to generate in NetBeans, I would need something similar for Intellij too. Thx in advance for your help.

[Generate JSF2 CRUD's - Can I create the bean and xhtml automatically for any entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274149/generate-jsf2-cruds-can-i-create-the-bean-and-xhtml-automatically-for-any-ent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own templates in IntelliJ IDEA: 

Go to: Settings > IDE Settings > File and Code Templates as below:

[image: Settings: File and Code Templates]

And then when you create a new class you can just select the template that you would like to use:

[image: Select your template]